# Difficulty with lineup of inner table inside a table cell

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I need to create a table with 1 row and 2 columns where the first cell has an inner table and the second a photo where I specify the width and let the system take care of the height. My difficulty is that I cannot get the inner table to line up at the top of the cell. To illustrate, here is the result I want:

[image]

and this is what I get

[image]

Also, [this is the link to the original picture used in the example](http://colman.hopto.org/DSC_3543.jpg)

I have tried all sorts of methods, from using `\parbox` and `\vspace` controls but after two days of reading manuals, googling and experimenting I'm admitting defeat and am now asking for help.

Here is the code which produced the badly formatted table.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular} {
    |@{}p{0.5\linewidth}@{}|
    p{0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|
}
    \hline
    \begin{tabular} {
        |p{0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|
        p{0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|
    }
        Serial Number & K77C 15229\\ \hline
        Reading & 18901 \\ \hline
        Date & 08/10/2012 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    & 
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pics/DSC_3543.jpg} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If I put `\vspace{0mm}` in front of `\includgraphics`, the inner tables appears at the top, as desired, but then extra white space appears above the photo. Putting a negative number (e.g. `\vspace{-6mm}`) produces the desired effect but then the number would need to change if the inner table had 4 or 5 rows. Since these need to be generated in the hundreds, it's not practical to have to manually adjust each one.

I feel as if I'm missing something simple. Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `adjustbox` package is your friend. Moreover the inner tabular should receive the `[t]` placement option:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc,adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular} {
    |@{}p{0.5\linewidth}@{}|
    @{}p{0.5\linewidth-\arrayrulewidth}@{}|
  }
  \hline
  \begin{tabular}[t] {
      p{0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|
      p{0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}
  }
    Serial Number & K77C 15229\\ \hline
      Reading & 18901 \\ \hline
      Date & 08/10/2012 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
  &
  \adjustbox{valign=t}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{DSC_3543.jpg}} \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}             
\end{document}
```

I've also fixed some of the computations, so that you'll not have padding left and right of the image.

[image]

Comment: `adjustbox`, not `adjustwidth`... :)

Comment: Wow! Great answer! Not only did you answer my question, but improved my limited understanding of measurements! Thanks.

Comment: PS @egreg - I would vote your answer up but I don't have enough "reputation" to do that :)

Comment: @user21172 You can accept the answer after seeing if nothing better comes along; also this increases one's reputation.